# differential inequality with $f$ and $f'$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, inequality

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function such that for all real numbers $x$ :

$$(f(x))^2+(1+f'(x))^2 \leq  1 .$$

How do you prove that $f = 0$ ?

I managed to prove that $f$ was bounded between $-1$ and $1$ , $f'$ between $-2$ and $0$ and therefore that $f$ was decreasing and I was trying to integrate the inequality but i'm stuck now .

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: do you mean $\leq$ instead? you can just edit it and write ```\leq```

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h472441p2645003

Comment: As mentioned on AOPS be sure to note that $f$ needs to be $C^\infty$ on all of $\Bbb{R}$ for this to work.

Comment: The solution proposed on AOPS only uses the differentiability of f

Comment: @VincentNIEL What if we replace $f'(x)$ with $\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y}$ but remove the differentiability? That is: Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function and $(f(x))^2+(1+\tfrac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y})^2 \leq  1$ for all $x\ne y$.